# Set the transperency of picker to low+iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i want to set the transparency of the picker such that it becomes invisible or very low.Can it be possilbe.please help me.

Thanks

Comment: whats 'the picker'? you can use the alpha property on a view to set transparency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
pickerView.alpha = 0.3; // or, a value from 0 to 1
```

Comment: @shweta, My answer was not that solution? :-0